# How to find the centroid of a drawn <circle> element in svg?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to find the centroid of the circle I am drawing like this;

```js
 circle = document.querySelectorAll('circle');
    console.log(circle.getBBox());
```

```html
<svg>
<circle class="donut-segment" data-per="30" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" 
fill="transparent" stroke="#254C66" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="50 50" stroke-dashoffset="75">
</circle>
</svg>
```

I get the error: Property 'getBBox' does not exist on type NodeListOf<\SVGCircleElement>.
Same goes with getBoundingClientRect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A *NodeList* is a collection, not a single element. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) always returns a NodeList, even if there is only one matching result. So: `circles = querySelectorAll(..); circle = circles[0]` Alternative, use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead, as that will only return the first found element.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.. and the above doesn’t “answer” the title question.

Comment: @user2864740 you were right, I have changed my code to iterate through all the circle elements instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For one circle select selector `querySelector('.donut-segment')`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 30 30" >  
<circle class="donut-segment" data-per="30" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" 
fill="transparent" stroke="#254C66" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="50 50" stroke-dashoffset="75">
</circle>
</svg> 
<script> 
circle = document.querySelector('.donut-segment');
 let cord = circle.getBBox() 
  console.log(cord.x + cord.width /2) 
   console.log(cord.y + cord.height /2)
</script>
```